# asset() returning //url... instead of http://url

Tags: php, laravel

Asset function not returning http:// or https:// before file path on rest api.

**SliderResource**

```
public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'title'=>$this->title_text,
            'photo'=>asset('assets/images/sliders/'.$this->photo),
        ];
    }
```

It should return a path like

```
"photo": "http://example.com/assets/images/sliders/image_name.jpg"
```

but its returning something like below

```
"photo": "//example.com/assets/images/sliders/image_name.jpg"
```

and here is `asset()`of **project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator**

```
 public function asset($path, $secure = null)
    {
        if ($this->isValidUrl($path)) {
            return $path;
        }
        $root = $this->assetRoot
                    ? $this->assetRoot
                    : $this->formatRoot($this->formatScheme($secure));

        return $this->removeIndex($root).'/'.trim($path, '/');
    }
```

> N:B Recently I have upgraded this project from laravel 5.6 to 7.0 and started building rest api. But it was working on 5.6, I am not sure if it is broken for upgrade because `asset()` working fine on everywhere in the project but in resource class.

Comment: `//example.com/...` is correct. That's a scheme-relative URL. It means your site will work no matter if it's `http://` or `https://` -- which is should be `https://` by the way. It's 2020, you should not be using `http://` any more.

Comment: ok that's good, so it could be used as img src dynamically?

Comment: Yes. There is nothing wrong here.

Comment: ok thanks for your reply, it was really helpful

Comment: if you have ssl then use `secure_asset()` instead of `asset()`